# Object Variable in script tasks

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my package, I have an Execute Sql Task that sets the result set to a User variable. I then have a c# script task that needs to reference this User variable as a result set. I need the entire result set sent into my script tasks as the web service I am calling needs the entire result set in one shot.

This is the current code I am testing with. It isn't much as I am still trying to figure out where to go with it.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated

```
public void Main()
{
    Variable resultSet = Dts.Variables["User::ZBatch_Order_Export_ResultSet"];

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

This is the update working code:

```
public void Main()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter oleDa = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    oleDa.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::ZBatch_Order_Export_ResultSet"].Value);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Dts.Events
           .FireError(0, "ZBatch - Script Task", row["orderDate"]
           .ToString(), String.Empty, 0);
        // Do some Webservice magic
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So very close, to access the `Value` of a variable, you need to hit that property

```
public void Main()
{
    Variable resultSet = Dts.Variables["User::ZBatch_Order_Export_ResultSet"].Value;

    // do stuff here with resultSet and the webservice

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;


}
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, I was not using .Value. I have updated my code to show how I did this.